# Override background image from parent element using CSS

Tags: html, css

In my application I have a section header with a caption and a horizontal line. The horizontal line is a background image (which contains the line, the rest of the image is transparent) of the parent container. The caption is defined by a child element.

```
<div class="header">
    <span>Identifier</span>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve - with CSS styling - is that the child element is displayed with the same background color as the parent, but the background image of the parent container should not be displayed underneath the caption.

```
.header {
    background-image: url("bg_image.png");
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
height: 25px;
}
.header > span {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

This works perfectly if I set the background color of the child element explicitly. But the background color can be configured by the user, so I don't want to set it explicitly.

So my the question is, is this possible at all using only CSS styling?

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dYr29/1/) shows the problem (I used a gradient to simulate the background image).

EDIT: An important requirement is that the solution must work across browsers (including IE8).

Comment: I guess I'm not following what you're trying to accomplish with the fiddle. So the `.header` css is fine? but the `.header > span` inside the header should only inherit the `background-image` but no the `background-color`? is that correct?

Comment: The `.header` css is fine, but the `span` should inherit the background-color, but not the background-image. Otherwise it looks like the text is striked trough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally identified how to solve the problem.

```
.header > span {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

Using `background-color: inherit` will solve the problem.
I also updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dYr29/4/).

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with a centered headline, try the css that i used in one of my projects:

```
h1 {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .2em 0;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;

  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #000;
}
h1:before {    
  left: -.5em;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50%;
}
h1:after {    
  left: .5em;
  margin: 0 -50% 0 0;
}
```

You can see the result here: http://codepen.io/DerZyklop/pen/AouDn

It is pure CSS. It adds two lines by using the css-pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after`.

With some modifications it should also work well with a left-aligned headline like in your example.

And another important thing to note here is the `white-space: nowrap;`. So this will only work with one line, but not with multiple lines.

Comment: @diwe mark my answer as correct (check mark) if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

can you please checkout 
http://jsfiddle.net/dYr29/3/
i have update your fiddle

```
<div class="header">
    <span>Identifier</span>
  </div>
```

css

```
    .header {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4c4c4c 0%,#595959 12%,#666666 25%,#474747   39%,#2c2c2c 50%,#000000 51%,#111111 60%,#2b2b2b 76%,#1c1c1c 91%,#131313 100%);
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 1px;
    top: 10px;
}

.header > span {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    top: -10px;
    left: 10px;
    background:#fff;

}
```

Comment: That is what I wrote in my inital statement, this works perfectly if I explicitly set the background color.
But I don't want to do that, because the background color of the parent element is configurable by the user.